# How to Update SQL Field from the same field in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, subquery, sql-in

```
 - **Date          | DocNumber**
 - ------          | 5000001
 - ------          | 5000001
 - ------          | 5000001
 - 28/02/2014      | 5000001
 - 28/02/2014      | 5000001
 - 31/12/2013      | 5000001
```

How to `update` the `empty date` with the `greatest date` for the same document number by using a subquery

Best regards
Essam

Answer (score 0):

```
Update mytable one
set one.date = (select max(date) from mytable two where two.docNumber = one.docNumber)
where one.date is null
```